# UITableView is nil in numberOfRowsInSection - no table displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboard, xcode4.6

I have added a UITableView in a 'Form Sheet' view controller via Storyboard. I have connected this UITableView to an IBOutlet in my header file. I have also control+click connected the UITableView to the dataSource and delegate outlets of the View Controller (used to be File's Owner pre-storyboard).

The delegate methods numberOfSectionsInTableView, numberOfRowsInSection, and heightForRowAtIndexPath are all called, but the UITableView instance in these methods is nil. Also, cellForRowAtIndexPath is never called. Of course, no table is being populated/displayed.

This is my first UITableView I've attempted via Storyboard. With XIBs I would just connect the outlets to File's Owner and all was good. What could be going wrong?

**CODE:**

header file

```
@interface LoginPopupViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UITableView *loginTable;
}
```

delegate implementation

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{    
    return 1;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    return 44.0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 2;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code for the table view delegate methods numberOfSectionsInTableView and numberOfRowsInSection. Since these methods return nil, the tables assumes there are 0 cells to draw and this never calls cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Also, make sure your storyboard uses "Dynamic Prototypes" and not static cells for the table if you're going to be using these delegate methods.

Comment: Oops, disregard the comment about not calling cellForRowAtIndexPath, I misread your post.

Comment: Code posted. Dynamic Prototypes is being used.

Comment: Are you using UITableViewController?

Comment: I'm not. I have added my header file to the code section.

Comment: Would you consider connecting it to a property rather than the ivar? `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView * loginTable;`   Above you said that you connected the delegate and datasource to the tableView.  That should be to the File's Owner similar to how you used to do it

Comment: @KHansenSF I tried that. Still no luck. To clarify, I connected the dataSource and delegate to the View Controller. Pre-storyboard it used to be the File's Owner. File's Owner no longer exists in Storyboard.

Comment: I don't see anything that should cause the problem you're describing. Maybe if you upload your project somewhere?

Comment: Uhhhh. Wow. So I deleted the UITableView I had added in Storyboard and added a new one in its place. Hooked everything up the same way. Now it works. I am at a loss for words. Thanks everyone for helping.

Comment: It appears that by resizing the prototype UITableView smaller in height, it made the code think that it was too small to add cells to even though it easily fit the necessary 2 prototype cells. I added a new UITableView of the default height and everything worked. I guess you can't resize UITableViews.

Answer (score 0):

> It appears that by resizing the prototype UITableView smaller in height, it made the code think that it was too small to add cells to even though it easily fit the necessary 2 prototype cells. I added a new UITableView of the default height and everything worked. I guess you can't resize UITableViews.

You can absolutely resize table views. In short, you need to fix your struts & springs (or constraints if you're using Auto Layout).

To elaborate, I'm fairly certain this is a combination of the following (easy to verify) conditions:

1. Your view controller's simulated metrics in the storyboard are taller the device (or simulator device settings). For example, if the storyboard is simulating 4" iPhone and you're testing on a 3.5" iPhone.
2. Your table view's struts & springs are fixed top margin, fixed bottom margin, flexible height (or equivalent Auto Layout constraints). This is the default storyboard behavior.
3. The height of your table view is smaller than the difference in simulated and actual height  of your view controller.

When all of the above are true, the table view will be resized to zero height in an attempt to preserve the top and bottom margins. Simply adjusting your struts & springs (or constraints) such that height is preserved will solve it. For example, try turning off flexible height.